# Wordpress template_redirect creates infinite loop after migration

Tags: php, wordpress

I just migrated a wordpress site to a new platform. For some reason the function

```
do_action( 'template_redirect' );
```

in wp-includes/template-loader.php redirects back to homepage in an endless loop.

In the log i also get this errror.

```
017/02/21 18:28:04 [error] 3339#3339: *2047 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: xx.xxx.x.xxx, server: example.com, request: "GET /cronreevaluateleads.php?run_st=7 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock:", host: "example.com", referrer: "http://example.com/cronreevaluateleads.php?run_st=7"
```

any clues?

Comment: please post this on http://wordpress.stackoverflow.com

Comment: @Jadeye meant http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Jadeye please flag the question and suggest the migration.

Edvard please show the code in your do_action(); Also this sounds like your DB records (where site urls are stored) is still referencing the old urls. Did you use the site export tool to do this migration?

Comment: Made title more generic so future users with a similar issue may find it. Removed the cgi tags as the question deals with php and wordpress.